Google Guice provider not creating instance of dependency
I am new to Google Guice and trying to figure out how it works. I have the following code where I created a module that provides implementations of the injected dependencies:
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.Provides;

public class GuiceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new TestModule());
        TestClass testClass = injector.getInstance(TestClass.class);
        testClass.test();
    }

}

class TestClass {

    @Inject
    SomeClass someClass;

    public void test() {
        someClass.test();
    }

}

class SomeClass {

    @Inject
    SomeDependency someDependency;

    public void test() {
        someDependency.test();
    }

}

class SomeDependency {

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("SomeDependency test");
    }

}

class TestModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {}

    @Provides
    public SomeClass provideSomeClass() {
        return new SomeClass();
    }

    @Provides
    public SomeDependency provideSomeDependency() {
        return new SomeDependency();
    }

}

SomeClass gets injected all good but SomeDependency is null in the SomeClass class. I am not sure why it would be null as I did define a provider in the module. What is the reason the SomeDependency instance would be null?

In provideSomeClass(), you are specifying that Guice should use the regular Java constructor to create an instance of SomeClass, rather than creating it with Guice. I don't think you should need either of your @Provides methods. (Mind you, I've never used field injection, I always use constructor injection)

As pointed out by Andy Turner, you are not asking Guice to create your instance of SomeClass but you are explicitly instantiating it in the method annotated with @Provides. If you remove that, Guice should be able to create  your instance of SomeClass by invoking its no-arg constructor.
